# My png files aren't showing on my website

Tags: html, png, transparent

My ribbon.png and logo.png both have a broken icon on my webpage while my fade.png is perfect. I have them with the correct path so I'm kind of stumped.  I should say as well that the difference in the 3 is that those 2 up there I deleted the background so that only the ribbon and logo show and the back is transparent not sure if I need to add special code for that. I'm seriously out of html practice so anyone have a tip?

```
html
<img src="ribbon.PNG" alt="Ribbon Picture" width="270" height="573" class="ribbon" style="height:auto " >
 <img class="logo" src="logo.PNG" alt="Logo" style="height:auto " />


css
div.fade{
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
height: 1400px;
width: auto;
top: 200px;
background-image: url("fade.png");
background-repeat: repeat-x;

}
img.ribbon{
position: absolute;
top: 600px;
left: 20px;
width: 229px;
}
img.facebook{
    position:absolute;
    top: 418px;
    left: 940px;

    }   

img.logo{
    position: absolute;
    top:20px;
    left: 250px;
```

Comment: Are they actually named `ribbon.PNG` and `logo.PNG` with capitalized extensions? If not, that's your problem.

Comment: can you browse to them via the full url? if you open up developer tools (f12) do the resources load when you open your website? what status code do these resources report?

Comment: Junkfoodjunkie you were absolutely right.  Such a rookie mistake.  Thanks I'll have to start remembering that again.